# Doesn't calling Entry.object.all() defeat the point of Django endless pagination?

Tags: python, django, pagination, django-endless-pagination

On https://django-endless-pagination.readthedocs.org/en/latest/twitter_pagination.html I'm reading that the example `views.py` might look like this:

```
from endless_pagination.decorators import page_template

@page_template('myapp/entry_index_page.html')  # just add this decorator
def entry_index(
        request, template='myapp/entry_index.html', extra_context=None):
    context = {
        'entries': Entry.objects.all(),
    }
    if extra_context is not None:
        context.update(extra_context)
    return render_to_response(
        template, context, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

This seems to indicate that we must call `Entry.objects.all()` and pass the results to the template. But doesn't `Entry.objects.all()` already make the query call to retrieve all the corresponding DB objects, defeating one of the main objectives of pagination (to retrieve small chunks of data at a time)?

Comment: Querysets are lazy. I don't know when this one evaluates (therefore can't provide a solid answer), but it's possible to continue to `.filter()` after a `.all()` is used.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Queries in Django are Lazy, that means that Entry.objects.all() does not bring the complete list of Entries, it just specifies the scope of the results Endless will show.

Comment: Would `Entry.objects.all()[0:10]` execute the query?

Comment: @personjerry Yes, Entry.objects.all()[0:10] will execute the query on SQL using LIMIT.